# Problem in setting up MATlink

Tags: matlab, matlink

I am trying to set up a MATlink using the instructions given here. I get an error while running the following commands

```
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]
```

Error:

```
The procedure entry point gzdirect could not be located in the dynamic
link library C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin\win64\libxml2.dll
```

Could someone suggest how this can be resolved?

EDIT: As suggested in the comment, I am also providing the output of

MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]

```
MATLink 1.1 for Windows (Fri 15 Aug 2014)

9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)

Force 32-bit engine: False

System PATH:
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Cuminas\Document Express DjVu Plug-in\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\windows\system32
C:\windows
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Users\yale\.dnx\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\runtime\win64
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin\win64
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps


COM server information:
CLSID: {0818548B-86E8-4451-87C2-AB70D68C490A}
Program ID: Matlab.Application (Version 9.7)
Command: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe /MLAutomation
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [troubleshooting notes](http://matlink.org/troubleshooting/), it is critical that you include the output of ``MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[] ``, otherwise we cannot guess at the cause of the problem. When you say "the instructions given here", did you forget to include a link to the instructions?

Comment: @Szabolcs Please find the updated post

Comment: Please evaluate ``SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{DirectoryName@FindFile["MATLink`"], "..","Engine", "bin", "Windows64"}]``. It will open a directory containing `mengine.exe`. Run this program manually (double-click it). What happens? You should get a small window asking to "Create link" with OK and Cancel buttons (you can just cancel).

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I get the small window with "Create link". Clicked cancel . Then I get another small window, clicked cancel for this one too. How should I proceed next? Please let me know

Comment: Can you restart Mathematica completely and try again?

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried it again. However, I get the same error `The procedure entry point gzdirect could not be located in the dynamic
link library C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin\win64\libxml2.dll`

Comment: Please join this chatroom and ping me (this might take a while) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102829/matlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that the "../libxml2.dll" file in other directory is used instead of *MATLAB installation directory*. The solution is adding or moving the *MATLAB installation directory* **at the start of the system path**.
As for me, here is the start of my system path. After adding the path, please **restart the Mathematica** and run the commands again.

[image]