# An Error in `MATLink`

Tags: matlab, matlink

I downloaded [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) to the directory generated by the command: (Matlab 2022b and Mathematica 13.1 on windows 10)

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

When I run the following code in Mathematica

```
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]
```

I got following error. (I also added Matlab to path on control panel)

```
OpenMATLAB::noopen: Could not open a connection to MATLAB.
```

I opened Matlab and run the code`enableservice('AutomationServer', true)`, the answer is `ans logical 1`
When I run the following code in Mathematica

```
MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]
```

I got

```
MATLink 1.1 for Windows (Fri 15 Aug 2014)

13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)

Force 32-bit engine: False

System PATH:
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin\win64
[Rest...]

COM server information:
CLSID: {CD797D1E-DEA7-47D3-AF1F-25C65DB6ED4A}
Program ID: Matlab.Application (Version 9.13)
Command: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe /MLAutomation
```

When I run the code `MEvaluate["magic(3)"]`
I got

```
MEvaluate::wspc: The MATLAB workspace is already closed.
```

I run also the following code in Mathematica
SetEnvironment[

```
"PATH" -> "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2022b\\bin\\win64;[Rest...]"]
```

Comment: Where did you see `MATLinkDeveloperGetInfo[]`?

Comment: I saw in your comment. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212285/problem-in-setting-up-matlink . But  It would be ``MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]``. I edited the post.

Comment: Debugging this may take a bit of back and forth between us, and that won't work very well on StackExchange. Can you please open an issue in the MATLink GitHub repo, and post the full, unedited output of GetInfo? If you are concerned about privacy, send an email instead. Be sure to restart Mathematica fully (including the front end) before loading MATLink and running GetInfo.